# How to update a firebase doc and not override existing values

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

The illustration shows my firebase db structure:

[image]

What I want to to is to to update a documents `Phonebook` entry with new values based on a specified doc id, The below code overrides all the doc values with the new values instead of updating.

```
insertPhonebookEntry(entry: any) {
if (entry.id) {
  this.db.collection('PhonebookEntries').doc(entry.id).set({
    PhoneBook: {
    Name: entry.name,
    PhoneNumber: entry.phonenumber
    }
  });
}
```

}

The `Phonebook` object is an array and has map value of `name` and `phonenumber`.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

[Use update() instead of set().](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/firestore/documents.md#manipulating-documents)

```
  this.db.collection('PhonebookEntries').doc(entry.id).update({
    PhoneBook: {
      Name: entry.name,
      PhoneNumber: entry.phonenumber
    }
  });
```

Comment: a new `phonebook` object is added and the existing one is not updated

Comment: If you just want to unconditionally append an item to an array, then you will want to use FieldValue.arrayUnion.  I don't know what the angular binding is, but the core docs are here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#update_elements_in_an_array